# Java file input stream reads 8 bits or 16 bits at a time

Tags: java, io

I was studying Basic IO in java from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

ByteStream reads one byte (8 bits) at a time. But the char are stored in 16-bit unicode character
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

My question or confusion is if the character is stored in 16 bits then how can FileInputStream's read method which reads 8 bit at a time can read 16 bits (in which character is stored internally)?

Comment: You don't read *charecters* from an `InputStream`. You can only read bytes or arrays of bytes. Proceed to the section "Character Streams" in that tutorial and you'll understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, strings are stored as arrays of `char` values, and a `char` is a 16-bit `UTF-16` encoded value. Some Unicode characters (e.g. emoji's) are encoded as 2 `char` values.

Files are sequences of bytes, so to store a string in a file the string has to be encoded. The encoding is called a Character Set, and it depending on which character set you use, whether a character takes up 1 byte, 2 bytes, or more.

These days, files are often encoded in UTF-8, so a Unicode character takes between 1 and 4 bytes.

In Java, the `InputStream` / `OutputStream` classes are used for reading / writing bytes. To read / write characters, you need to use a `Reader` / `Writer`, which is usually done by wrapping an `InputStream` / `OutputStream` with an `InputStreamReader` / `OutputStreamWriter`, which you specify which character set should be used to convert bytes to / from `char` values.